# how to search USB printer which is connected with router?

Tags: java, printing, usb, snmp, router

I'm trying to search the usb printer which is connected with router(Netgear PR2000) in java code , i tried to use SNMP protocol to get the printer's info from router but get no response.

what i want to do is  , search the printer then setup the connection via socket and send the data for printing. can someone share some thoughts on this , thanks very much.

Comment: My first thought is that this should be done through OS, not directly from Java code. This may help: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/

Answer (score 0):

```
PrintService[] services = PrinterJob.lookupPrintServices();
for (int index = 0;  index < services.length; index++) {
    System.out.println(">>"+services[index].getName());
}
```

similar questions are:

[How to use Java to print on a network printer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11230502/how-to-use-java-to-print-on-a-network-printer)

[Java application to print on Network printer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9098853/java-application-to-print-on-network-printer)